# "The preferred Swiss chocolates" or "The preferred Swiss chocolate"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

Would you say

> The preferred Swiss chocolates

OR

> The preferred Swiss chocolate

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your context. If you are talking about a specific type you would use "chocolate", but if you were referring to an aggregate of several different types of chocolate (e.g. the different chocolates sold by Lindt), you would use "chocolates".